# Storing a value in variable from resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Executing the following query '`SELECT ID, CODE FROM SAMPLE_TABLE`' Which returns

```
ID  CODE
1   45
5   45
6   45
7   45
8   45
```

i will be storing it in a temp table. In all case the CODE remains same for each rows for a result set.

I want to get the code value and set it to the variable without any subquery
like

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (ID) SELECT ID, @CODEVAL = CODE FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
```

But the above code doesnt works for me. Is there any other way to set the value to variable without doing querying ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to do an `INSERT` and store the value of `CODE` field of the source table into a variable at the same time.

The closest you can get at your aim is to use a *table variable* and use `OUTPUT` clause of the `INSERT` statement:

```
DECLARE @CODEVAL TABLE(CODE int)

INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE(ID, CODE)
OUTPUT  INSERTED.CODE
INTO @CODEVAL
SELECT ID, CODE
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE

SELECT * 
FROM @CODEVAL
```

**Output:**

```
CODE
====
45
45
45
45
45
```